# How to convert string values to numbers using parseInt in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, post, parseint

I am facing an  issue of converting string  value to  numbers when i pass into my input field. I have used parseInt but instead getting an NAN value .

Here is my input field in html:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <label>Form id:</label>
 <input type= "text" name="fromId" class="form-control" ng-model="IssueReceipt.formId" ng-required="true" readonly> <span class="error" ng-show="issueReceiptDataEntryform.fromId.$dirty && issueReceiptDataEntryform.fromId.$error.required "></span> 
                            </div>
```

And my script page where i pass the value :

```
$scope.getRandomForm = function() {
          paymentService.NewEReceipt().success(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                $scope.IssueReceipt.formId = parseInt(data);
                console.log(parseInt(data));
             })

        }
        $scope.getRandomForm()
```

Let me show u the console i'm getting :

[image]

If i use parseInt, i'm getting NAN as the value instead of number. 
Please can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: @Jaganathan Bantheswaran The value i'm passing is an  API value . The data in the controller i'm passing consists of values in it.

Comment: @Jaganathan Bantheswaran I'm getting the values . but, it is in the form of string .but, i need it in numbers.

Comment: I aware that `data` is string. The reason i told you to trim the string `data` is to avoid the space if any in the string. Try like this `parseInt(data.trim())`

Comment: @Jaganathan Bantheswaran i tried but still getting as NAN value .

Comment: Its strange that parseInt returns NaN though the string is proper number. I am excited to see the answer which you are going to accept

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128503/discussion-between-anil-chean-and-jaganathan-bantheswaran).

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me. I have hard coded the value in controller instead of data. You can send ur entire code so that I can check or just trim the data or debug and check it might be a simple issue

```
$scope.getRandomForm = function() {

      var data = "12345";
      $scope.IssueReceipt.formId = parseInt("12345");
       console.log(parseInt(data));


    }
    $scope.getRandomForm();
```

i am getting output as 12345

Comment: @ Ajay kumar The value i'm passing is an API value . The data in the controller i'm passing consists of values in it.

Comment: ohh okay.. Got it @anilchean

Answer (score 0):

First convert the response data into string and then parse it into integer this might be help try once

```
 paymentService.NewEReceipt().success(function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                  var returnId = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $scope.IssueReceipt.formId = parseInt(returnId);
                    console.log($scope.IssueReceipt.formId);
                 })
```

Comment: still i'm getting an NAN value

Comment: `data` is already of type string. You dont want to convert that

Comment: Try json.parse and then convert to int

Comment: @ Sujithrao   is this the method you are telling       paymentService.NewEReceipt().success(function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                    $scope.IssueReceipt.formId = data;
                    return JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                 })

Comment: @Sujithrao the API method that  i'm  using is an  Post method .

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer finally

```
 paymentService.NewEReceipt().success(function(data){
                //console.log(parseInt(data.trim()))
                $scope.IssueReceipt.formId = JSON.parse(data);
                //return JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
             })
```

Have used  `$scope.IssueReceipt.formId = JSON.parse(data);`which converts string to numbers.

Comment: How does `JSON.parse` differs from `toString` or `stringify` or `trim` in terms of string value as input and outpu